# FB.login() Not working on Firefox?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When clicking Login, a function called login() and request for Facebook permissions. However while it does work on Chrome and Opera, it doesn't do anything on Firefox.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        window.location = "<?=$loginUrl?>";
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
```

I have added an alert just before this code, and it runs when clicking the login button. So the problem is solely with facebook's login code.

You can see my login page on http://justwalk.it/login

Also there is no "a popup window was blocked" or warning of the sort. Anybody experienced this? What could be the reason for which it doesn't work on firefox?

Comment: If you open up FireBug, in the Net panel, do you see a request going out that's being blocked (in red text).  Also, are you sure the callback URL is setup correct on the developers.facebook.com site?

Comment: It works well for me in Firefox at your site.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your network and Firefox certificates.

Open Firefox and in search tab type `about:config`, click on I accept the risk and find preference `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` and set it to `true`

After this it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.facebook.com.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```